# Euler 35 - python solution taking too long

Tags: python, optimization, algorithm, project-euler, primes

Here is my solution for Project Euler 35. (Find the number of circular primes below 1,000,000. Circular meaning all rotations of the digits are prime, i.e. `197`, `719`, `971`.) The code takes about 30 minutes to run. Can you help me identify which parts of the algorithm are hogging up computation time?

I know there are many solutions out there, I just want to know why this one is soooo slow. I suspect it has something to do with the `p.count` function call.

- `p` is initialized to a list of all primes below 1 million using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.
- `total` is initialized to 0.

```
for i in p:
    primer = str(i)
    circ = 1
    for j in range(len(primer)-1):
        primer = primer[1:]+primer[:1]
        if (p.count(int(primer)) == 1):
            circ += 1
    if circ == len(primer):
        total += 1
```

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12389/13523

Answer (score 7):

Your `p` is a list.  Then you do `p.count(x)` to see if x is a prime.  This does a linear search of the list, and in fact, has to examine every element of `p`, not just those up to the occurrence of `x`.  Instead, change `p` to a set.  It will run much faster.  Also, once you see that a rotation is not prime, you can stop checking all the rotations.

Answer (score 3):

*All* primes below a million?  You only need the ones that consist of the digits 1, 3, 7, or 9.

Edit: And the single-digit circular primes 2 and 5.

Comment: Your total would be off by 1: you would miss 2!  But good point!

Comment: While accurate if he were only concerned with primes > 10, this optimization would actually produce the wrong answer because 5 counts as a circular prime according to the problem description.  It's a good idea if you special case 5 though.